# How can I show the user login block on the 403 page?

Tags: views, 8, users, path-aliases

With D8, I have a node (content type: basic page) that I use as a custom 403 (access denied) page.

I set this as the custom 403 page on: `/admin/config/system/site-information`.  The path is `/node/21`, and the alias is `/error/403`.

On the block admin page, I added the **user login block** to the **content** region.  I added the restriction "show only on certain pages":

- /error/*
- /view/*
- /node/21

I have a view that requires "add content type ABC permission" to access.  The path to the view is `/view/abc`.  The anonymous user does NOT have this permission.

So, as an anonymous user, I go to `/view/abc` and am shown the content of `/node/21`.  BUT, the user login block is not shown.

If I go to the block administration screen and remove the "show only on certain pages" restriction, then I see the block as the anonymous user on `/view/abc`, but I don't want to show the login block on every single page; I only want to show it on the pages that are 403s.

What is the "path" to use for the user login block to only show it on a custom 403 page?

Comment: You need a visibility condition. There is a patch or a contrib module (the module is for 404's, but you can adjust it for 403's), see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260304/prevent-path-based-breadcrumb-in-theme-or-dont-show-breadcrumbs-for-403-404-r

Comment: Have you seen this one already: https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_login? And this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2245767?

Comment: I am curious if it's possible to redirect from the 403 to your node ID... Then just don't set the node as default 403 page. Somewhat related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165884/how-to-redirect-an-anonymous-user-to-the-login-form-after-a-403-error/165888. And I've never tried but can you add a `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()` like `system.403` to the admin page? Or the `Pathauto` or `redirect` module? Or hook into these path elements?

Comment: Probably a bit late but there's a module to add options to show blocks for error pages here: https://www.drupal.org/project/http_client_error_status.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to add page templates to your theme registry:

```
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  //Allow theming the site error pages
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

  switch ($route_name) {
    case 'system.401':
    // Unauthorized Access.
    $error = 401;
    break;

    case 'system.403':
    // Access Denied.
    $error = 403;
    break;

    case 'system.404':
    // Page Not Found.
    $error = 404;
    break;
  }

  if (isset($error)) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $error;
  }

}
```

Then in `page--403.html.twig` you can render a specific block with Twig. See: [How to embed a view in a specific node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/140647/how-to-embed-a-view-in-a-specific-node) and [Programatically print blocks in twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207377/programatically-print-blocks-in-twig)

*A reason I like this approach is that the Login block is a Drupal core block, not a custom one. You can just carry around a nice `403` template file and always know it will render out this block. The preprocess function above seems like the least invasive and time consuming (from looking at different approaches), plus it gives the ability to theme these error pages. I think it is ideal to utilize template files for error pages.

Comment: But where's the login block?

Comment: Not 100% this resolves the issue of the "path" not applying in the block settings, but this would allow the use of twig to render out a specific block.

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222360/custom-block-in-custom-404-node.

Answer (score 0):

If you can code, you should go for a ConditionPlugin.

Just like RequestPath*(ConditionPlugin) we built a custom RouteCondition plugin. That allows us to have granularity on each route.

In your case, a simple ConditionPlugin could be the proper starting point.

Here is an example * (www/modules/custom/{your_module}/src/Plugin/Condition/NotFoundCondition.php)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\{your_module}\Plugin\Condition;


use Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionPluginBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'Error Pages 403' condition.
 *
 * @Condition(
 *   id = "error_403_pages",
 *   label = @Translation("Error 403 Pages"),
 * )
 */
class ErrorPages extends ConditionPluginBase {

  /**
   * @return bool
   */
  public function evaluate() {
      //  Retrieve the current route
      $route_name = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();

      // Does we have a match
      return strpos( $route_name, 'system.403') === 0 * $this->isNegated();

    // EDIT: the negate concept might be a bit overwelming at first.
    // Maybe you don't need it right now

  }

  public function summary() {
    if (!empty($this->configuration['negate'])) {
      return $this->t('Do not return true on 403 pages');
    }
    return $this->t('Return true on 403 pages');

  }
}
```

After a cache rebuild you should be able to place the login block on 403 page using structure>block layout

Comment: What is the FormStateInterface doing there? It's unused, innit? And where's the login block???

Comment: FormStateInterface was an artifact. I edited the post.

Comment: Whereas a custom condition plugin is a good idea, your example won't work, if a custom node is used as error page. In this case, the most reliable way is to check the exception attribute from the request for being an instance of AccessDeniedHttpException.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz You are right. I didn't have this in mind.

Comment: If a custom node would be used the block display can easily be limited to be shown only on `/node/123` – the 404 node. Another possibility actually to solve the problem.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz, exactly, this is how the patch and the module in the linked question implements the condition. You can get the exception type also with `getStatusCode()` on the exception object. The patch doesn't care, its condition is for all exceptions, but the module does. See the plugin code of the module https://cgit.drupalcode.org/block_in_page_not_found/tree/src/Plugin/Condition/PageNotFoundRequest.php

Comment: @4k4 – What a gem!

Comment: @4k4 The status code is not as reliable as well. I unfortunately don't remember the exact scenario. In a similar use case we had occasions where checking the exception worked, but the status code didn't.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz, I'm not against checking the instance of the exception class. As you've explained, the crucial part is the presence of the request attribute, which then contains an exception object. You can investigate the object in your debugger and choose a method to determine the type that fits best. The method chosen by the module seems to work though too in most cases, because there are no issues filed saying otherwise.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz, I think you probably used the request attribute `_exception_statuscode` in earlier D8 versions, which was removed some time ago.

Comment: @4k4 Agree. Have to admit, the site in question made heavy use of throwing not found exceptions for users without access on admin paths, and 403 on quite a lot of non existing pages for logged-in users. The aim was to obfuscate URLs from prying eyes and prevent from guessing URI patterns. Probably this played a role in our above mentioned case.